# How to add Infragistics set of controls in VS2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, visual-studio

I'm trying to add a Infragistics NetAdvantage control, but the control isn't shown anywhere. Does Visual Studio 2010 support Infragistics controls?

Comment: I expect that specific VS version support will depend on your version of Infragistics. If I were debugging this, here's what I would do: 1) Make sure that Infragistics is installed on the PC; 2) in Visual Studio go to Tools -> Choose Toolbox Items, and make sure that all of the Infragistics assemblies that you intend to use are ticked.

Comment: yes sir but infragistics is not shown so how to include?

Comment: @PawanKumarTiwari that's what Kirill already posted. If you don't understand what `Choose Toolbox Items` does, you should look for an introductory *course* on .NET in general. As for Infragistic and Visual Studio support Yes/No/Maybe. Infragistics controls are *made for Visual Studio*. It supported Visual Studio since Day 1. If you try to install the latest version though, it probably *WON'T* support VS 2010 because it's far too old. It's not even supported by Microsoft anymore

Comment: Here is also important which version of the Infragistics Controls you are referring to? Which platform you are targeting as well? There are tools that could help you in certain versions to add the Infragistics Controls for you in the toolbox, but it depends on the one that you are currently trying to use.